# How does an Invoker with Hand of Fury interact with summons and persistent dailies?

Tags: dnd-4e, divine

Hand of Fury:

> Benefit: When you miss all targets with a daily invoker power, you can use hand of radiance as a minor action once before the end of your turn.

A sample power:
Angelic Protector:

```
Daily        Divine, Implement, Summoning
Minor Action      Ranged 5
Effect: You summon a Medium angelic protector in an unoccupied square within range. The angel has speed 6 and has a +2 bonus to AC. You can give the angel the following special commands.
  Standard Action: Melee 1; Wisdom vs. Reflex; 2d12 + Wisdom modifier damage, and the target is marked until the end of your next turn.
  Opportunity Attack: Melee 1; targets one creature; Wisdom vs. Fortitude; the target is immobilized until the end of your next turn.
```

Given that the summon's standard action is the result of a daily power, does missing on the power trigger Hand of Fury?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my translation:

> When you miss all targets with a daily invoker power.

"Miss" typically requires an attack.  So, in order for the power to possibly trigger this, an attack must be involved in the power's execution.

> You summon a Medium angelic protector in an unoccupied square within range.

This is not an attack.  It is a summoning.  Anything beyond this (available commands, etc.) is a rider effect which occurs separate of the power's usage.  Therefore, neither this power nor the commands made available by it, may trigger Hand of Fury.

Comment: The power lacks an attack line so neither hits, nor misses. The something else that the power creates that can hit or miss, is a something else, that is not a "daily invoker power". So, yes, I agree.

Comment: @Simon - There are only two types of powers (Attack, Utility).  Angelic Protector is clearly labeled as an Attack.

Comment: @PatLudwig - It has the Attack keyword, but the power does not have an Attack line or require usage of an attack roll - which is the issue at hand.

Comment: +1. Further, what exactly were the targets the invoker is directly attacking with **Angelic Protector**? The power doesn't have any targets, so it wouldn't qualify for the benefit of the feat anyway. Even if it does count as an attack, the power doesn't affect any targets so you couldn't meet the feat's requirements that way.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!  Here is my **interpretation**.

> When you miss all targets with a daily invoker power

When, and how often does this trigger is key.

I believe this can only trigger when the power is fully resolved and no longer exists in any way.  This means that the invoker could use Hand of Radiance after the angelic protector is dismissed or killed as long as it missed all targets with its attacks.

Comment: I'm so glad I don't particularly agree with this answer :) Must not give you more points...

Comment: @Brian - well, I didn't see any definitive, but what I gave works for me as an explanation.  I figure it's better to get some opinions out there to vote on.

Comment: Yeah. there's nothing... definitive out there. And yeah, the "any time you miss" is a bit... abusable. Bleh. So not impressed with invoker.